# Have a unique name per game on Steam

Tags: steam, hell-let-loose

I have multiple games on Steam and one game, Hell Let Loose, I am in a clan that requires a different name than the one I wish to use. I want to keep my original name and have it be changed only when I am playing Hell Let Loose. Is there any way that some tool can detect game activity and automatically change my Steam profile name?

Answer (score 1):

No, Steam does not has a feature to set different names per game.

For your purpose, I think you could use the Clan Tag option that is in the Gameplay Options. This can be set to up to 4 characters representing your clan.

[image]